# Upgraded from F35 to F36 now video and audio doesn't work

Tags: video, nvidia

On F35, everything worked fine.  I was able to view all videos, local, netflix, youtube, plex, etc.  After upgrading

```
$ dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=36
$ dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

My multi (4) display worked just fine but I was unable to view videos on YouTube.  I get a message over the video
[image]

For local videos, they start in a frozen state.  Everything else just buffers.  I followed these steps https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/#before-installation but that did not help anything as far as I can see.  I then tried https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/6/ but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been strictly an audio issue.  It makes sense since the videos did come up, they just didn't play although I was thinking it would play but have no sound if it was an audio issue.  Anyway, I changed the Profile and it started working.

Activities -> Pulse Audio Volume Control -> Output Devices.  Select the device and choose the correct configuration profile under Configuration.

[image]